# how to make parent model's variables as not required in child model, provided all the parent variables are marked as required?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I have a parent definition which is extended by a child definition using allOf keyword. Since i have marked all the variables as required in parent model , it is being marked as required in child ,model too. But i need the **parent variable to be marked as not required**. Any ideas?

```
definitions: 
  Parent:
    type: "object"
    required:
      - "id"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
        minimum: 1
        example: "123456"        

  Child:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/Parent"
    type: "object"
    required: 
      - "sample"
    properties:
      sample:
        type: "string"
        format: "full-date"
        example: "2001/12/31"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot un-require a parent model's fields in child models. The workaround is to define a base model, say, `ParentBase`, with optional properties and inherit both `Parent` and `Child` from this model.

```yaml
definitions:
  ParentBase:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        minimum: 1
        example: 123456

  Parent:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/ParentBase"
      - required:
          - id

  Child:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/ParentBase"
      - type: object
        required: 
          - sample
        properties:
          sample:
            type: string
            format: full-date
            example: "2001/12/31"
```

On an unrelated note, the `id` property is defined as an integer but its example value is a string. This is wrong - the example data type should match the property type. You need to use `123456` without quotes.

```yaml
id:
  type: integer
  #example: "123456"  # Wrong
  example: 123456     # Correct
```